# Different URL for each GeoJSOn feature

Tags: url, leaflet, geojson

I have a map which loads a GeoJSON file with multiple line features. When I click a line, the map performs some action (in this case, it's changing the bounds and adds some text underneath it).

```
var trails = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('https://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/trasee.geojson', {
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    layer.on({
        click: function() {
            map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
            $('#description').html('some text ' + feature.properties.id);

        }
    });
}
}).addTo(map);
```

Is it possible to have a different URL for every line, so I can access a particular feature directly (for example, https://websiteurl.com#thisfeatureid)? The link would load the map with the bounds and description of the selected feature.
Here's a JSFiddle of the map:

http://jsfiddle.net/pufanalexandru/qxbuwaeg/

Answer (score 0):

Given a url for a trail such as https://websiteurl.com#5, here's one approach.

1. When the document is ready (leaflet loaded, geojson loaded, map initialized), but before you set the map bounds, use javascript or a URI parser to check for the param for trail id from the url. Simple example:

   ```
   var trail_id = document.URL.split('#')[1];
   ```
2. If you get an id, search the trails features for a match on that id, and zoom to the bounds, just as you already are on click

   ```
   trails.eachLayer(function(layer) {  
       if (layer.feature.properties.id == trail_id) {
           map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
           $('#description').html('some text ' + feature.properties.id);
           return; 
       }
   }
   ```